# I have the following error while building Cool Mic

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
External Native Build Issues
Build command failed.
Error while executing 'C:\Users\rojina\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
make: *** No rule to make target `A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/src/main/jni/opus/opus/opus_sources.mk'.  Stop.
Build command failed.
Error while executing 'C:\Users\rojina\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
make: *** No rule to make target `A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/src/main/jni/opus/opus/opus_sources.mk'.  Stop.
A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\opus\Android.mk
Error:(3, 0) A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/src/main/jni/opus/opus/celt_sources.mk: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\opus\Android.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(4, 0) A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/src/main/jni/opus/opus/silk_sources.mk: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\opus\Android.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(5, 0) A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/src/main/jni/opus/opus/opus_sources.mk: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\opus\Android.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(3, 0) A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/src/main/jni/opus/opus/celt_sources.mk: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\opus\Android.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(4, 0) A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/src/main/jni/opus/opus/silk_sources.mk: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\opus\Android.mk">Open File</a>
Error:(5, 0) A:/Freelancer/CoolMicApp-Android/app/src/main/jni/opus/opus/opus_sources.mk: No such file or directory
<a href="openFile:A:\Freelancer\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\opus\Android.mk">Open File</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps:-

```
How to build coolmic:
1. Download Android Studio and the NDK
2. Clone this repository
3. Run the following commands:
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
4. Import the Project into Android Studio. Select gradle-wrapper. 
5. Hit build(Arrovdown with 011001 next to it. 
6. Hit the Build Menu and then Build APK
7. You can find the resulting APK under ./app/build/outputs/apk/
```